# faster coding in bash: one-liner templates

Tags: bash, templates, autocomplete

Using the `bash` is often tedious, not least because there is often some overhead.
I want to speed up my bash coding with some kind of macro, since I am not the fastest typer.

An use case would be to copy `a.out` to some (sub)directories :

```
mkdir subdir{1..5}
echo "123" > a.out
for d in $(ls -d subdir*); do cd $d; pwd; cp ../a.out .; cd ..;done
```

where I repeatedly use the body

```
for d in $(ls $PATTERN); do $COMMAND ;done
```

with some `$COMMAND` in a broader context. One option to accelerate would be a bash function.

```
function loop () {
  for d in $(ls $1); do $2 ;done
}
```

But since the bash has an auto-completion mechanism and also the wonderful ctrl+r search, I wondered if there's a smart trick that utilized this mechanisms to make the body appear on the bash prompt directly. The ideal scenario would be to type some predefined keyword like `loop` in the bash and upon pressing TAB (or some other shortkey(s)) the body

```
for d in $(ls $PATTERN); do $COMMAND ;done
```

shows up in bash (and still can be manipulated).

To make clear what I'm thinking about: This is a standard feature in editors like vscode, where I can type `func`, a dropdown menu appears and I can select some body to get `function ### (###) {###}` written out.
Such a macro would definitely help me in other situations, too, whenever I have to use the same body many times.

Any ideas? How do *you* deal with the mentioned overhead in bash?

Comment: `echo "123" | tee subdir{1..5}/a.out > a.out`

Comment: There's also `for d in subdir*; do cp ../a.out "$d"/a.out; done`, and `for d in subdir*; do pushd "$d" && ... && popd; done` if you really have need to change the working directory.

Comment: `for d in $(ls $PATTERN)` is [wrong](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- let the shell use the pattern directly: `for d in $PATTERN`

Comment: You could define a readline [binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax).

Comment: Thanks to the hint how to improve my bad subdir-copy command. This was an use case example for the broader question of auto-completion mechanisms in bash, which was answered by Fravadona excellently.
@glennjackman Your right about the `ls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a completion function for the `for` keyword?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

_for() {
    COMPREPLY=()
    if [[ ${#COMP_WORDS[@]} == 2 ]]
    then
        COMPREPLY=( 'd in PATTERN; do COMMAND; done' )
    fi
}

complete -F _for for
```

Then try to type: `for` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Innovative idea!

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for. So there is a way of customizing the bash auto completion directly - I didn't know that.  Thanks!

Comment: @zufall Yes, you can define/redefine the completion function for any command/keyword/alias and even commands that don't exist; but don't overdo it, if you take a look at `/usr/share/bash_completion` you'll see that the common ones that we all use are quite complex to write, so overriding them for expanding their functionalities is no easy feat; doing it for the `for` keyword should be OK, overall.